# IIS Rewrite file.png to index.php?file=file.png

Tags: iis, web-config

I don't know how to redirect:
"https://images.url.com/c/test.png"
to:
"https://images.url.com/c/index.php?file=test.png"

```xml
<rule name="filerewrite" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^c(.*)$" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="false" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="c/index.php?file={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

It still says:

> 404 or redirect to index.php?file=c/index.php?file=c... and so on

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your pattern.

If you use your pattern, then {R: 1} is "/test.png"

You can try to change you pattern as below:

```
^c/(.*)$
```

Best regards,

Sam